# Fetch Javascript-blob()-URL.createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, blob, javascript-metodo

Hola estoy usando la api fetch en javascript y por alguna razon al almacenar mi imagen o ruta de imagen en un blob y luego a su vez utilizarlo con el metodo URL.createObjectURL()
me aparece este siguiente error en consola: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src')
at exercise.js:6

Al parecer es un problema con el .src no entiendo porque no me lo agarra normalmente?
adjunto el codigo HTML:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FETCH-final</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Final Fetch</h1>
<button id="btn">image</button>
<button id="btm">pdf</button
<img id="imag" class="imag">
<a id="pdf" href="#"target="_blank">Descargar</a>
</div>



</div>
<script src="/exercise.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>

Y ahora el codigo javascript:



const botomimg=document.getElementById("btn")
const botompdf=document.getElementById("btm")
botomimg.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    fetch("/salchipapa.jpg")
    .then(res=>res.blob())
    .then(res=>{document.getElementById("imag").src=URL.createObjectURL(res)})

})
```

Comment: No consigo generar ese error. ¿No será que tienes un error tipografico aquí? `<button id="btm">pdf</button` pues no cierras el `</button`... le falta un `>`

Comment: Wow increible nose como deje pasar ese error, muchas gracias, se solucionó!

Answer (score 2):

Fue un error en el html al no cerrar el button correctamente.